# Limited access of website in particular country

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an eCommerce website, developed in Codeigniter 3.0.6. The site has 5-6 products categories. I want to control category and products access like:

- Category 1: shows only in the USA
- Category 2: in India

Could anyone tell me how to control this through admin panel?

Comment: use IP address of the visitor to find the country and then logic as per products . Extracts data from IP like this sites tell you about ip details https://www.iplocation.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to have a geolocation library to translate visitor's IP address into country code for direction. Please download and set up the geolocation library https://github.com/ip2location/codeigniter-ip2location, and then add the code in your index (or any function that you want the redirection happens).

```
    //get the ip address
    $ip = $this->input->ip_address();

    //get country code by IP address
    $this->load->library('ip2location_lib');
    $countryCode = $this->ip2location_lib->getCountryCode($ip);

    //perform redirection based on country
    $this->load->helper('url');
    if ($countryCode == 'US'){
        redirect('/watches');
    }
    else{
        redirect('/gadgets');
    }
```

The above code will get the IP address using ip_address() field, then it will pass the value to ip2location_lib to retrieve 2 digits country code. Lastly, it will check the country code for redirection. For example, redirect to watches page if visitors coming from US.

Comment: It works, but sometime IP address fails to get locations. Anyway thank you for sharing.

Comment: The sample bin inside my github was not up to date. You need to download the latest from https://lite.ip2location.com and update this into /libraries/ip2location/ folder.